# How can I serve dynamic content in Node.js using StrongLoop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I'm pretty new to Node.js, but the [StrongLoop Docs](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+middleware#Definingmiddleware-Routingmiddleware) don't really give out any concrete examples. I'm using Handlebars for my templates, and am just trying to serve a standard `index.js` pre-compiled template. I know I'm supposed to edit my `routes.js` file, but I don't know how to do it.

This is what my `routes.js` file looks like:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    // I need this to serve my index.js file.
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Doesn't work, so I commented it out:
        // require('views/index.js');
        // Doesn't work, so I commented it out:
        // res.requires('views/index.js');
        // Doesn't work, so I commented it out:
        // res.send('views/index.js');

        // What do I put here then?
    });
    // This is the generic example. Just sends text.
    app.get('/ping', function(req, res) {
        res.send('pong');
    });
};
```

Just to clarify, when I say it Doesn't work <sup>TM</sup>, I mean typing in `localhost` displays the 404 catch-all route. Yes, that's `localhost`, and not `localhost:3000`. It's working on port 80.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm trying to convert a skeleton loopback application to a full-stack app/api server (with data accessible from both outside and inside the server).

Answer (score -1):

1. Add static middleware to the files property in middleware.json
2. Delete server/boot/root.js.
3. Create client/index.html
4. Start the server via slc run and browse to localhost:3000

I maintain a full example for this use case here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-middleware#how-do-you-serve-static-content-via-static-middleware

Let me know if you need anymore help. ;)

Comment: what the OP is asking is how to handle dynamic pages in loopback. you are talking about static pages..